# EC2 instance with partitions for /boot as ext4 and root / as lvm possible?

Tags: amazon-ec2, lvm, boot, root, amazon-ami

I've been playing about with this for a few days now. I haven't managed to find an example of someone running an EC2 instance with the root volume partitioned to have /boot on ext4 (or 3 or 2) and then / on lvm.

So far I've managed to create an instance that will recognise the /boot partition and start to boot from it, but it fails to find the LVM partition so crashes:

> dracut Warning: LVM VolGroup00 not found
>
> dracut Warning: LVM VolGroup00/lv_root not found

Given that I cannot find any reference to anyone doing this before. Maybe it's just not possible for some reason?

Lyle

Comment: There's not much point to separating `/boot` on EC2. The whole reason it was done in the first place was to work around restrictions on partition sizes in old PC BIOSes, which mostly don't exist anymore, and certainly don't in that virtual machine.

Comment: Michael: I'm separating boot as EC2 cannot boot from an LVM partition, as per it's documentation:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/UserProvidedKernels.html

Comment: Right, neither can Linux generally. So that's a reason to do it. You'll probably have to create your own AMI.

Comment: Michael: I have created my own AMI. That's how I've got to this point. Did you down vote me because you didn't read this question was about LVM on /??

Comment: I didn't downvote your question, but perhaps I should. It's clear you need to significantly expand it.